# Write to a Bluetooth LE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can I write to a miniBeacon Characteristic in android permanently so that after writing when I scan the device next time I will get the updated characteristic value? Can I make the characteristic value password protected so that reading a particular characteristics require a password?